# How to make overlapping links clickable

Tags: html, css

Lines height in my div is a little smaller than font size by design, so that links are overlapping. First two of them are partly clickable.

```
<div style="width:25px;line-height:8px;">
    <a href="/link1" style="font-size:10px;z-index:10;">link1</a>
    <a href="/link2" style="font-size:10px;z-index:9;">link2</a>
    <a href="/link3" style="font-size:10px;z-index:8;">link3</a>
</div>
```

I already tried to set higher z-index to higher links as I showed in my sample, but it doesn't help.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pQ4RV/

Comment: make a fiddle with the problem so people can help

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for z-index to work you need to specify

```
position: relative;
```

on the elements you're specifying the index for.

But in general you should fix your line height problems not write a workaround using z-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Give `<a>` a position: relative, so z-index will work.

CSS:

```
a {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/76dH7/